# What is the default TextAppearance of the NavigationView drawer items?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx, android-navigationview, material-components

I would like to put a custom `actionLayout` item on my `NavigationView` drawer items. I want the text inside the `actionLayout` to look as close as possible to the exiting menu items on the `NavigationView`. I know I can use my own custom `TextAppearance` for `NavigationView` items but I would just prefer to reuse the one that `NavigationView` items are already using or at a minimum use it as a parent my custom one.

So what is the `TextAppearance` for `NavigationView` items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the default style used by the `NavigationView`

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
    <item name="itemTextAppearance">?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle2</item>
    ...
</style>
```

where:

```
<item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
```